# Installing on USB stick

Tags: boot

I have the live system running from USB stick.  (13.04) It boots straight into it so no issues there. However, when I go to install option and can choose another USB stick to install full system. The installation churns away concludes to it's satisfaction but then won't boot. Am I selecting thw wrong options somewhere or can't you install 13.04 on a stick?

---

Tried all which ways to get it to boot from USB stick. Brings back memories of when I first tried to get Linux to work 20 years ago. It is still very unfriendly at the base level.

Comment: Are you using Something Else or manual install? That is the only way to get the option on which drive to install grub2's boot loader into. All the auto install options install grub to sda.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Installing_Ubuntu_to_a_Specific_Partition_.28.22Something_Else.22.29:

Answer (score 0):

Check out bug 384633.  USB to USB install results in the wrong device being used.  Used to be always one too high (e.g. sdc instead of sdb, hd2 instead of hd1) but since 12.04, that seems not to be the  case as consistently.  At the first grub screen when booting the newly created USB, type e to edit the commands, and see what disks are being used -- the uuid will be OK, but any actual device is suspect -- change as necessary.  AT first successful boot, run

```
sudo update-grub
```

to fix things.

---

For UEFI machines, you 1)need to make an EFI partition (FAT32, 300M, boot flag) on the USB, and when installing, identify that PARTITION as the boot loader device.  Otherwise, the hard disk's EFI partition will be used (even when giving the target DEVICE as the grub device).

Comment: Seems to be loading 13.04 onto correct stick. Seems as if Grub is not being installed.

Comment: Solved it by installing Grub 2 on laptop. You guys can figure out why that works